# How to move an item from a list "A" to list "B" when a checkbox is clicked in list "A"?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow

Is there a good tutorial which can show a SharePoint novice how to move an item from a list "A" to list "B" when a checkbox is clicked in list "A"?  I have attempted to use a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 following a tutorial, which has just confused me! Please help!

Comment: Could you attach and image of your current workflow?

Comment: I attempted to create one, but it got confusing with action part so I actually haven't created one.

Comment: http://www.fivenumber.com/copy-item-from-one-list-to-another-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow/    does look like it will help?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an event receiver, capturing the updated event.
Follow this guide to learn how to create one:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/create-a-custom-list-level-event-receiver-for-item-added-in/

In the updated event ask if your flag field is checked, if it's then use the moveto property of the document library class, like this:

```
SPListItem item = oldLib.GetItemById(1); 
SPFile file = item.File;
file.MoveTo(newLib.RootFolder.Url + "/" + item.File.Name, true);
```

If you need more help just ask :)